# how to remove rows with specific character in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, character

I am trying to export some links from a website html file to a datagridview. The problem is some href attributes values in html file are: #.
I want to delete the rows with value of #. I try blew code but it doesn't work and nothing happens.

```
 private void findsuburls(string str,DataGridView dgv)
    {
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = web.Load(str);
        foreach (HtmlNode pages in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='pagination   ']/li/a[@href]"))
        {
            dgv.Rows.Add(pages.Attributes["href"].Value);
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[0].Value == "#")
                dgv.Rows.Remove(row);                  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you filter them out when adding rows in the first place?

Comment: And aren't you getting any error/warning? because you can't modify the collection iterated inside a `foreach` loop

Comment: @Fildor how can I do that, I don't know how to filter them.

Comment: @Pikoh no there isn't any error. the code compile and run without problem.

Comment: `var temp = pages.Attributes["href"].Value; if( temp != "#" ) { dgv.Rows.Add(temp) }` for starters.

Comment: thank youuuu @Fildor, it works.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, it isn't answering your question :(

Comment: @Fildor It is. maybe I just ask it badly. That's exactly what I wanted. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filter them out when adding rows in the first place.

```
 private void findsuburls(string str,DataGridView dgv)
    {
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = web.Load("http://goldtag.net"+str);
        foreach (HtmlNode pages in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='pagination   ']/li/a[@href]"))
        {
            var temp = pages.Attributes["href"].Value;
            if (temp != "#")
            {
                dgv.Rows.Add(temp);
            }  
        }     
    }
```